# Visualizing a "stacked" bar chart for individual entries?

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart

I'm attempting to make a "stacked" bar chart in R in order to look at the composition of a person's sales portfolio. The data looks something like:

[image: data sample]

with many more sales people (Mr. C, Mr. D, etc) and annualized bookings for each sale, which is my point of interest. I have

[image: aggregated bar chart]

using ggplot2 that shows no stacking and simply the total annualized booking of all sales each person sold, shown by the code:

```
g <- ggplot(data1, aes(Sales.Person)) 
g + geom_bar(aes(weight = Annualized.Booking)) + 
  labs(title = "Sales Person Comparison") + 
  labs(y = "Annualized Booking total")`
```

Is there a way in ggplot to visibly stack the individual sales, so as to see the composition of the total sales portfolio? Or is a stacked bar chart not the optimal solution for this?

Comment: Did you check the [ggplot website](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_bar.html)? Infor there: *By default, multiple bar occupying the same x position will be stacked atop one another by position_stack. If you want them to be dodged side-to-side, use position_dodge. Finally, position_fill shows relative proportions at each x by stacking the bars and then standardising each bar to have the same height.*

Comment: Welcome to SO. Pictures aren't code or data unless the questions is about image processing.

Comment: Please do not provide your data as an image.  No one wants to type it all in.  Instead, please use  `dput(data1)` to get a text version of your data that you can paste into your question and we can paste into R.  If your data is too long, just use `dput(head, data1, 10))`

Comment: You could just add `fill = factor(Annualized.booking)` .. or `fill = factor(1:nrow(data1)` ?

Comment: sorry about the pictures! I will take that into account from now on, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like that (as @erocoar remarks)?

```
data1 <- data.frame(
  Sales.Person = c("A", "A", "C", "B", "B", "A", "C", "C"),
  Annualized.Booking = c(115000, 139000, 50100, 120500, 80400, 10400, 50500, 75000)
  )

ggplot(data1) + 
  aes(Sales.Person, Annualized.Booking, fill = factor(Annualized.Booking)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  labs(title = "Sales Person Comparison") + 
  labs(y = "Annualized Booking total") + 
  guides(fill = FALSE)
```